# What happens when i use RTK Query with redux-persist?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist, rtk-query

What will happen when i use Redux Toolkit Query with redux-persist?

Will it use the persisted state or will the state be refetched?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an [official guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist) for this now. At the time of writing this, you could configure it this way:

```js
// store.ts
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

import someSlice from 'config/features/someSlice'
import { api } from 'config/services/api'

const reducers = combineReducers({
  someSlice,
  [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
})

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage: AsyncStorage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers)

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      // Redux persist
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }).concat(
      api.middleware,
    ),
})

export let persistor = persistStore(store)

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

```js
// App.tsx for native or index.tsx
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
```

Comment: Adding to that, since I implemented that functionality: My comment below "usually, you should not do it" still stands. This should only be used in edge case scenarios, usually you should just fetch the data from the server again.

Comment: By “edge case scenario“ you mean something like a React Native app with offline-first functionality when the app is launched and there is no connection (see https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-offline-first-react-native-app/)?

Comment: As that is probably in the single digits of the user base, yes. Also, in a scenario like this there is a good chance you want to go for a library that offers normalized state instead, not a document cache like RTK Query is, as that way you can do at least some level of client-side search functionality etc., which is not what a document cache is meant for.

Comment: Any libraries you would recommend in particular?

Comment: no, not really. There is no "one size fits all" scenario since REST Apis are so different, so there is already not one good solution for a normalized cache scenario - adding "offline" on top of that makes it even more difficult. You'll have to try out many and see what works best for you.

Comment: I had do use blacklist in persistConfig as the official documentation now mentions, ignoredActions wasn't enough for me

Answer (score 9):

I just really wouldn't do it.

That restored data could be all kinds of stale and when a user hits F5 they usually expect data to be up-to-date, not a week old or something. Also, while the store slice is restored, information about subscriptions might be problematic (because the "subscribing components" never exist, they can also never unmount and thus get never cleaned from the store).

So, I'd blacklist the api slice from being persisted.

If you want that stuff to be cached, do it with cache headers in your server. The browser will do all the caching for you, but also allow the user to clear the cache or force a refetch with ctrl+shift+r - so the browser would just behave more than the user expects.

Comment: Is it safe to persist a slice where I keep my authentication token or should that be avoided too?

Comment: Depends if you have an alternative for it. If you can avoid it, avoid it (use a httpOnly sameSite secure cookie and never let it touch JS), but if you can't avoid it there is not really an alternative.

Comment: @phry Though you are right about the web apps perspective, how about progressive webapps ? We do need to store the data for offline capability isnt it ?

Comment: Tbh, I would do something like that much more transparently on a service worker level than on the app level. But either way, RTK 1.7 will probably contain a way to hydrate correctly from persistance, but it's still WIP. Trying it out & feedback is welcome though: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/1277

Answer (score 3):

Use `extractRehydrationInfo` like this:

```
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist'

export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
    if (action.type === REHYDRATE) {
      return action.payload[reducerPath]
    }
  ...
  },
```

Full official guide [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/persistence-and-rehydration).

Comment: say I want to do this, is this the only config I need to do or is there another config required? do I still need to add the store to persist-gate? there's no holistic example of how to do this.

Comment: also, I am looking to persist the logged-in user whose token has not expired upon page refresh. with the old way, there's a straightforward way of doing that.

Comment: Login is usally a POST request, which means it is a mutation in rtq query. you can create a separate reducer for auth data and persist that reducer specifically. I still don't know how to persist rtq query data, the docs are not complete like you said. checkout this file: https://github.com/obayit/odoo-react-native-client/blob/main/src/common/store/reduxApiStore.js

Comment: I achieved mine same way by blacklisting the rtk-api and then using the auth alone for redux-persist