# How to persist cached data beyond a phone reboot or app closure using Redux Toolkit Query with React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist, rtk-query

As the question suggests, I'm trying to figure out how to persist cached data beyond a phone reboot or app closure using React Native with Redux Toolkit Query. I've noticed that the cached data gets wiped in those scenarios. I believe that caching data beyond an app closure or phone reboot is a common practice.

I have thought about simply storing the data in client-side Redux using Redux Persist to get around this issue, without persisting the api slice. As this post indicates, persisting the api slice is a bad idea:
[What happens when i use RTK Query with redux-persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943867/what-happens-when-i-use-rtk-query-with-redux-persist).

Any tips on this would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I can only repeat what I already said in the other issue:
I do not recommend doing this. Data from a server should be fresh, and this way it defitely won't be.

That said, we are currently working on SSR integration and that, too, will need similar functionality. So some kind of rehydration mechanism will be integrated, probably in Redux Toolkit 1.7 - but until then you have the choice between not keeping api data cached (again, my recommendation. No user wants to open an app and see data from five weeks ago - rather show them a loading screen!) or restoring it, but potentially ruining cache collection of said data.