# React Redux Tookit Query - Migration

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a question regarding RTK Query migrations.

To be clear: I am not wanting to migrate from one library to RTK Query, but I want to add a field or Tag to my query. The query results are saved in the store, but sometimes when you want to add a new field which is not in the old store, the new code can crash.

I have problems when adding a new field of adding a new `Tag`. I solved it by resetting the whole store, but this is off course not nice in production.

In the "old" way (when I only used RTK, not RTK Query) I used to use `createMigrate()`.

Thx in advance!

*my old code I wrote a migration like this:*

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  version: 8,
  migrate: createMigrate(migrations, { debug: MIGRATION_DEBUG }),
};
```

Comment: If you're asking about using `redux-persist` to persist the "API slice" data from RTK Query... we actually specifically recommend that you _don't_ do that.  Let RTKQ refetch that data when the app starts.

Comment: Thank you, this made things much more clear. Another question, I have one slice which stores auth information ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72607334/redux-toolkit-query-react-access-data-in-other-component-without-parameters?noredirect=1#comment128270855_72607334)) and cannot be done using RTK Query. So I (think?) I need to persist one slice. How can I do so? I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943867/what-happens-when-i-use-rtk-query-with-redux-persist) implementation, but it seems "not recommended" to do so.